# How can I call add a LARGE title to my visual studio 2005 chart

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Forgive the simple question but I am brand new to Visual Studio and I have a bar graph with a 'chart title' already but I need to add a larger and bolder title to the top of my project in addition to the already existing title.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is this Visual Studio the programming GUI?  Are you writing code, using the SQL Server reporting plugin, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chart Properties there is a field called Titles. You can add as many as you like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, would you mind helping me with this: http://superuser.com/questions/453161/i-renamed-my-visual-studio-2005-file-and-now-i-cant-reopen-my-report